# Connection to SignalR Hub fails with Negotiate 404 (not found)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, signalr

I've been researching this issue for 3 days now and cannot find a solution.  I created a SignalR Hub with the following code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace Messenger.Hubs
{
    public class MessengerHub : Hub 
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Simple enough, the startup code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Messenger.Hubs;

namespace Messenger
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("c:/myapp/Messenger");
            });
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

I pretty much cut and pasted the code from a solution posted on the internet somewhere, I forget where, not stackoverflow though.  I then created the following client in a Xamarin (v4.12.3.81) project using Visual Studio 2017 (v15.9.10).  That code is:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;

namespace SignalR.Client.Hubs
{
    public class SampleHub
    {
        // MessengerHub is a appliaction folder aliased as MessengerHub
        // the direct path on the machine is c:\mywebapp\messenger
        private const string _hubUrl = "http://example.com/MessengerHub";
        private readonly HubConnection _hubConnection;
        public event EventHandler<string> OnMessageReceived;

        public SampleHub()
        {
            var builder = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(_hubUrl);
            _hubConnection = builder.Build();
        }

        public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
                _hubConnection.On("messageReceived", (string platform, string message) =>
                {
                if (OnMessageReceived != null)
                    {
                        OnMessageReceived(this, string.Format("{0}: {1}", platform, message));
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = ex.Message;
                //Console.WriteLine($"Connection error: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public async Task<int> GetNumberAsync(int number)
        {
            return await _hubConnection.InvokeAsync<int>("GetNumber", number);
        }

        public Task Send(string message)
        {
            return _hubConnection.SendAsync("Send", message);
        }
    }
}
```

The code in the activity that uses that client is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using SignalR.Client.Hubs;


namespace MyXamarinApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "Messenger")]
    public class Messenger : Activity
    {
        protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Messenger);

            RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
            try
            {
                var input = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Input);
                var messages = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.Messages);

                var inputManager = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(InputMethodService);
                var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, new List<string>());

                messages.Adapter = adapter;

                var hub = new SampleHub();


                await hub.ConnectAsync(); // <---- fails here

                input.EditorAction +=
                  delegate
                  {
                      inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(input.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);

                      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.Text))
                          return;

                      hub.Send(input.Text);

                      input.Text = "";
                  };

                hub.OnMessageReceived +=
                  (sender, message) => RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    adapter.Add(message));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The hub is (I believe) running correctly on the server, I set logging on and this is what is in the log:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\mywebapp\Messenger
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

The attempt to connect to the hub generates the following error:

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 404 (Not Found)

  at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode () [0x0002a] in <25ebe1083eaf4329b5adfdd5bbb7aa57>:0

  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection+<NegotiateAsync>d__44.MoveNext () [0x00226] in <843c441fa9954906b53e3710152bebb9>:0

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
  --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection+<GetNegotiationResponseAsync>d__51.MoveNext () [0x00077] in <843c441fa9954906b53e3710152bebb9>:0

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
  ---
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection+<SelectAndStartTransport>d__43.MoveNext () [0x00169] in <843c441fa9954906b53e3710152bebb9>:0

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
  ---
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection+<StartAsyncCore>d__40.MoveNext () [0x00118] in <843c441fa9954906b53e3710152bebb9>:0

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
  --- at System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult () [0x0000c] in <843c441fa9954906b53e3710152bebb9>:0

  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection+<StartAsync>d__39.MoveNext () [0x0008b] in <843c441fa9954906b53e3710152bebb9>:0

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
  --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HttpConnectionFactory+<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext () [0x0009d] in <d50de232736c4c8f910083ea0cb358a8>:0

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
  ---
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HttpConnectionFactory+<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext () [0x00142] in <d50de232736c4c8f910083ea0cb358a8>:0

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
  ---
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection+<StartAsyncCore>d__47.MoveNext () [0x00130] in <f381011e9b214489bcb373743f31ed9d>:0

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
  ---
 at System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult () [0x0000c] in <f381011e9b214489bcb373743f31ed9d>:0

  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection+<StartAsync>d__39.MoveNext () [0x00091] in <f381011e9b214489bcb373743f31ed9d>:0

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
  ---
  at SignalR.Client.Hubs.SampleHub+<ConnectAsync>d__6.MoveNext () [0x00037] in C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\signalr_client\signalr_client\Resources\layout\Client.cs:28 }
```

This is what I see in the IIS Log for the site.

```
"POST /MessengerHub/negotiate HTTP/1.1" 303 446
"GET /MessengerHub/negotiate HTTP/1.1" 404 1509
```

I have no idea what to try next.

Comment: You have `chatHub` in the server but are trying to use `MessengerHub` in the client.

Comment: Just a class name, changed it ... made no difference, exact same issue.

Comment: If you have a hub declared like this: public class ChatHub:Hub then you have to ensure you camel case the reference: routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub"); (this would work). However, this will not work: routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub"); Nor will routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/ChatHub"); Not sure what you changed aboved as you are not showing the change.

Comment: Apparently the issue is with the server somehow not finding signalr, it doesn't matter what I put in the routes.MapHub, the server is looking for a folder called `negotiate` on the path defined in routes.MapHub which doesn't exist in the configuration.  No idea where that comes from or how to fix it.

Comment: FYI ... I copied the hub code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.2, runs in IIS Express, apparently not IIS 8.5.

Comment: Try replacing “ c:/myapp/Messenger" with “/MessengerHub”.And I guess the server isn’t running at example.com so make sure you use the right host huburl here “private const string _hubUrl = "http://example.com/MessengerHub";

Comment: Did that, same result.  Still looking for `negotiate` folder which isn't there of course.  I don't know why it's looking for the `negotiate` folder there's no mention of it anywhere in the code and the hub works fine in IIS Express, just won't work on IIS 8.5 on server 2012 R2 and no one has an answer.

Comment: Are you hosting signalr locally or is it accessible via ip other than `localhost`? And how do you test mobile application, emulator or phone?

Comment: However nvm, IIS logs tells us that you reach it. So make sure you have `routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/url");` on server and `private const string _hubUrl = "http://example.com/url";` on client. It works as intended

Comment: The URLs is setup properly. I'm hosting the hub on a Windows 2012 R2 server with IIS 8.5, I test via browser and android phone. Right now I'm using the browser right out of IIS Manager to "browse" the application. I've been modifying the javascript to debug errors. I was getting the same negotiate error I was getting with the phone connection, now something has changed. Still not working, not sending messages to clients, but not failing on the connection to the hub now. I have now idea why, and all I did was add alerts to the script.

Comment: Nevermind, syntax error, it was never hitting the connect code. Same problem. Sigh ... thought I was on to something. lol

Comment: @PrescottChartier Could you try just to run asp net core as console application and test it via browser?

Comment: Given my inexperience with signalr, I doubt I could do that easily.  lol ....

Comment: Any solution on this? Why negotiate getting added to URL?

Comment: I switched to the legacy SignalR aspnet solution, works just fine.  I Was never able to get aspnetcore to work, just didn't have the time to play with it and no answers on the net.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this error today and after some rather wasted time I had simple forgot to add:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<FooHub>("/FooHub");
});
```

To the Startup.cs >> public void Configure(...) in my .NET 5 ASP.NET application.

Things have changed a little since this was originally posted (and I did see some Xamarin) but hopefully this gives somebody some guidance in the future.

Comment: in .NET  7 this causes ASP0014 violation: Suggest using top level route registrations - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/asp0014?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @user8207463 This warning is only generated for minimal apis

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SignalR NetCore 5, Blazor webassembly project when deployed to IIS, worked fine in localhost on dev machine.

The solution was to use full url in the hub connection:
First include hub endpoint in the Startup.cs

```
 endpoints.MapHub<BroadcastHub>("/broadcastHub");
```

Then when setting up the hub connection, instead

```
   hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
              .WithUrl(navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/broadcastHub")
                 .Build();
```

use full url:

```
     hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://myserver.com/bcwa/broadcastHub")
            .Build();
```

bcwa is my IIS deploy folder